# How to restrict user to display login page if already logged in using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs framework, I am working on "Login Logout" module and i just want that if user already logged in ( email set in cookie) then he should redirect to "dashboard" page,How can i do this ? I tried with following code but not working for me, giving me error ",Here is my current code

```
cookies returned from getServerSideProps Reason: undefined cannot be serialized as JSON
```

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context: { req: { headers: { cookies: any; }; }; }) {
    
  const cookies = context.req.headers.cookies;
  if (cookies && cookies.email) {
    // email is present in cookies, so redirect to /dashboard
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/dashboard",
        statusCode: 302, // temporary redirect
      },
      props: {},
    };
  }
  
  return {
    props: {
      cookies,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When returning `props.cookies` from `getServerSideProps`, you are potentially returning the cookies as `undefined`. Use `''` as the default value if missing.

You can do this:

```
  return {
    props: {
      cookies: cookies || '',
    },
  };
```

Comment: : const cookies = context.req.headers.cookies; giving me "undefined"  as response in console.log

Comment: yes, that is why I am suggesting to use default value value returning it. `cookies: cookies || '',`

Comment: let me explain , actually after login cookie is showing in "network->cookie" section but then i tyring to open index/login page then page is showing and in console showing me "undefined" but actually "cookie" (email) exist , showing me undefine,Hopefully you understand my point

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the cookies and you can get the cookies on the request you don't need the header

```
const cookies = JSON.parse(context.req.cookies);
if(cookies.email !== undefined)...
```

Comment: i am getting following error "Property 'cookies' does not exist on type"

Comment: @Maria change getServerSideProps(context: {req... to just getServerSideProps(context)

Comment: now i am getting error  "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 "

Comment: @Maria do you actually have any cookies set? can you see the cookies in the browser debug?